# Reference books on Lambert function

Tags: analysis, reference-request, lambert-w

Does anyone have a good reference book on the Lambert W function? I need it as reference for my thesis particularly, as reference for this

> The general solution to $$x=a+be^{cx}$$ is $$x=a-\frac{1}{c}W(-bce^{ac})$$

I found this on Wikipedia but it does not link the actual reference. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Not a book, but a standard reference on Lambert W is the paper of Corless, Gonnet, Hare, Jeffrey and Knuth in Advances in Computational Mathematics, which is reference #1 in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a book by I. Mező](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0367766833) from 2022 that might work for you. It deals with the equation $x+b^x=a$ in section 1.1.3, and from that you should be able to derive the result you quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can also provide a proof yourself in your thesis. It is easy:
\begin{align*}
x &= a + b{\rm e}^{cx} 
\\[1ex]
x - a &= b{\rm e}^{cx} 
\\[1ex]
(x - a){\rm e}^{ - cx}  &= b
\\[1ex]
(x - a){\rm e}^{ - cx + ac} & = b{\rm e}^{ac} 
\\[1ex]
(x - a){\rm e}^{ - c(x - a)} & = b{\rm e}^{ac} 
\\[1ex]
 - c(x - a){\rm e}^{ - c(x - a)} & =  - bc{\rm e}^{ac} 
\\[1ex]
 - c(x - a) & = W( - bc{\rm e}^{ac} )
\\[1ex]
x & = a - \frac{1}{c}W( - bc{\rm e}^{ac} ).
\end{align*}